# Changing enumerate to Thai label

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, polyglossia

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{TH Sarabun Chula}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage[Latin, Thai]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionTo{Thai}{\thaifont}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt

\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item A
         \begin{enumerate}
             \item a
             \item b
         \end{enumerate}
   \item B
         \begin{enumerate}
             \item c
             \item d
         \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

I want to change (a), (b), ... to ก., ข., ... (Thai language). I have tried using `enumitem` package but it clashed with `polyglossia` package and cause many problems. Using `polyglossia`to change the enumerate might be the way to go but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of default enumerate counters in [`source2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e)

[image]

And now one can create a custom counter for enumerate, in your case for Thai alphabet

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@thaialph}[1]{%
 \ifcase#1\or ก\or ข\or ฃ\or ค\or ฅ\or ฆ\or 
 ง\or จ\or ฉ\or ช\or ซ\or ฌ\or 
 ญ\or ฎ\or ฏ\or ฐ\or ฑ\or ฒ\or 
 ณ\or ด\or ต\or ถ\or ท\or ธ\or 
 น\or บ\or ป\or ผ\or ฝ\or พ\or 
 ฟ\or ภ\or ม\or ย\or ร\or ฤ\or 
 ล\or ฦ\or ว\or ศ\or ษ\or ส\or 
 ห\or ฬ\or อ\or ฮ\or ฯ\or \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*{\thaialph}[1]{\expandafter\@thaialph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother
```

And whenever you want to use the counter, add this command before your `enumerate` environment.

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thaialph{enumi}}
```

---

Alternatively, you can redefine styling of each enumerate levels by changing `\labelenumi`, `\labelenumii`, `\labelenumiii`, `\labelenumiv`, etc.

For example, setting this will make all first level list have `1)`, `2)`, ... numbering and all second level enumerate list will have Thai alphabet numbering in parentheses.

```
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi})}
\renewcommand*\labelenumii{(\thaialph{enumii})}
```